# Is there a way to write CSS styles without app reload in angular 4? #LiveStyle #LiveReload

Tags: css, angular, less, angular-cli, livereload

Is there a way to write CSS styles without app reload with angular 4.3. / angular-cli ? Just like Emmet LiveStyle.

I use LESS for preprocessor.

Comment: If you use webpack for less processing then you try this https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/

Comment: Not sure how to try it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found that I need HMR (Hot Module Replacement) for this purpose. Here is the article I used:

'Enable HMR in Angular CLI apps' by Bram Borggreve
https://medium.com/@beeman/tutorial-enable-hmr-in-angular-cli-apps-1b0d13b80130